# Is there a way to write the command itself to the output file?

Tags: regex, windows

I am on Windows 7. I am using the following command to find all occurrences of forms being displayed from VB source files in the current directory -

```
 findstr /n frm.*\.Show *.* > FormsDisplayed.txt
```

This command works perfectly, and FormsDisplayed.txt now holds all occurrences of statements like

```
 frmXYZ.Show vbModal
```

However, is there a way to write the command itself to the FormsDisplayed.txt file? I mean, is it possible to write the string "findstr /n frm.*.Show *.* > FormsDisplayed.txt" to the FormsDisplayed.txt file, so that I know what command was used to generate the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a command file (aka batch file) with the name of your choice, let's call it x.cmd, with just one line:

```
%*
```

you'll need to put it either in the current directory or somewhere on the path.  You can then say

```
x findstr /n frm.*\.Show *.* > FormsDisplayed.txt
```

and it will do what you want, i.e., the findstr command will appear at the top of FormsDisplayed.txt (so will the command prompt, which by default shows the current directory).

If you don't want the full command prompt to show, put this in the command file:

```
@setlocal
@prompt $H
%*
```

(Type prompt /? at the command line to see other options for the prompt command.)

Comment: Wow!! This is magic!! What does the percent star do? I understand that the rest of the command is being passed as arguments to x.cmd.

Comment: %1 is the first argument to the command file ("findstr"), %2 the second argument ("/n") and so on.  %* is the entire string, exactly as it appears on the command line.